# Adding data in an array

Tags: javascript, data-manipulation

I have some data I need to do some computations/manipulation on:

```
data=[{"sex":"M","age":"0","pop":"310"},
{"sex":"M","age":"5","pop":"306"},
{"sex":"M","age":"10","pop":"313"},
{"sex":"M","age":"15","pop":"332"},
....
{"sex":"M","age":"100","pop":"4"},
{"sex":"W","age":"0","pop":"294"},
{"sex":"W","age":"5","pop":"291"},
{"sex":"W","age":"10","pop":"300"},
{"sex":"W","age":"15","pop":"318"},
....
{"sex":"W","age":"100","pop":"1"}
]
```

I extract the sub data for male (M) and for female (W) :

```
var male=data.filter(function(d){
if (data.sex=="M"){return d.pop;}
})
var female=data.filter(function(d){
if (data.sex=="F"){return d.pop;}
})
```

Now, I would like to compute the population (pop) for both sex i.e. create a new variable named "both" containing with respect of the variable "age" :

```
both=[{"sex":"MW","age":"0","pop":"604"},
{"sex":"MW","age":"5","pop":"597"},
{"sex":"MW","age":"10","pop":"613"},
{"sex":"MW","age":"15","pop":"650",
....
{"sex":"MW","age":"100","pop":"5"}
]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to combine the M and W entries into a single entry with a combined `pop` value, by age. If so, you need to create a map of the entries by age and add the `pop`s together, which you can fairly easily do in ES5 using an object (in ES2015 — aka "ES6" — you'd probably use a `Map`). Then convert it back into an array when you're done. See comments:

```js
// Your data -- note that I've fixed the pop values, if they're
// meant to be numbers, they shouldn't be in quotes
var data = [
    {"sex":"M","age":"0","pop":310},
    {"sex":"M","age":"5","pop":306},
    {"sex":"M","age":"10","pop":313},
    {"sex":"M","age":"15","pop":332},
    {"sex":"M","age":"100","pop":4},
    {"sex":"W","age":"0","pop":294},
    {"sex":"W","age":"5","pop":291},
    {"sex":"W","age":"10","pop":300},
    {"sex":"W","age":"15","pop":318},
    {"sex":"W","age":"100","pop":1}
];

// Create the "map" of entries by age:
var byAge = Object.create(null);
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    // Get the entry for this age, if any
    var ageEntry = byAge[entry.age];
    if (!ageEntry) {
        // None, create and add it with an initial pop of 0
        ageEntry = byAge[entry.age] = {sex: "MW", age: entry.age, pop: 0};
    }
  
    // Add in the pop for this entry
    ageEntry.pop += entry.pop;
});

// Convert it back into an array (if you want):
var result = Object.keys(byAge).map(function(key) {
    return byAge[key];
});

// Show result:
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes !! It's exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
    {"sex":"M","age":"0","pop":310},
    {"sex":"M","age":"5","pop":306},
    {"sex":"M","age":"10","pop":313},
    {"sex":"M","age":"15","pop":332},
    {"sex":"M","age":"100","pop":4},
    {"sex":"W","age":"0","pop":294},
    {"sex":"W","age":"5","pop":291},
    {"sex":"W","age":"10","pop":300},
    {"sex":"W","age":"15","pop":318},
    {"sex":"W","age":"100","pop":1}
];
var ages=[]
for(var i=0;i<data.lenght;i++){
   if(!ages[data[i]['age']]){
       ages[data[i]['age']].push({"sex": "MW", "age": data[i]['age'], "pop":data[i]['pop'] })
    }else{
      ages[data[i]['age']].pop +=data[i]['pop']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the reduce method would work for what you need.

```
`var population = ARR.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return Number(a.pop) + Number(b.pop);
 });`
```

Note that you must cast the string representation of the population to a number, or it will be concatinated.